# Does “a book launch” mean “a book launch event”?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-usage, expression-choice

> 1. **A book launch event** announced to be held in Berlin last summer was
>    canceled.

> 2. **A book launch** announced to be held in Berlin last summer was canceled.

Does ‘a book launch’ in 2 *clearly* mean ‘a book launch event’? Can I omit event with no worry about ambiguity?

Comment: Closely related: [Is the phrase ‘Berlin book launch event’ correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/594785/is-the-phrase-berlin-book-launch-event-correct)

Comment: @Mari-LouA They are two different questions, and you know that Mari-Lou. That question was about several nouns in a row, whereas this one is about whether the meaning of two phrases are the same.

Comment: I didn't vote to close it as a duplicate. I said "related".

Comment: @Mari-LouA OK. But there seems to be no point in saying that.

Comment: In corporate world, if you have hardware issue, you may be told "Contact IT Dept" which becomes "Contact IT". If you have financial query, you may be told "Contact finance Dept" which is shortened to "Contact finance". In same way, "book launch event" is almost equal to "book launch". In your case, there may be some ambiguity : Was the book launch itself canceled ? Or only the book launch event was canceled ? You may want to include something like either "the book was eventually available in stores without fanfare" or "the book launch event was in winter" or "the book is still not available".

Comment: @Prem The books might be available anyway. The event was canceled. But the question is whether ‘a book launch’ can mean ‘a book launch event’ too.

Comment: That is what I said [[ In same way, "book launch event" is almost equal to "book launch". ]] I also reiterate that when "event" is removed, it is not clear whether "only the event" was cancelled or "the whole launch" was cancelled.

Answer (score 2):

> A book launch event [to be held in Berlin.]

If the launching of a book is one of many similar initiatives that was held in Berlin then the indefinite article "a" is appropriate. If instead the OP is mentioning a book that the reader is familiar with, then I would use the definite article: "**The book launch**".

I am not convinced that including *event* is always redundant as suggested by [one user's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/594807/44619). In my opinion,  *an event* hints at a party, a stuffy presentation, or the opportunity to meet the book's author in person.  A launch, on the other hand, could be limited to an official announcement in newspapers, radio and on social media. It could be rather low-key and on a tight budget.

- Illness prevented her attending **the launch** ***party*** for her latest novel.
  <sub>Cambridge Dictionary</sub>

Remove "party" and the meaning changes.

- **The *event*** got off to a shaky start with the stage lights failing in the first few minutes.
  <sub>Cambridge Dictionary</sub>

Replace *event* with *launch* and the reader would know what the event was  and guess the venue was perhaps a theatre or television studio.

However, *a book launch event* sounds awkward to my ears. The following are suggestions but by omitting "event", the launch sounds less significant.

> 1. **The book launch** planned to take place in Berlin last summer was cancelled
> 2. **The event** planned for the book launch in Berlin was cancelled last summer.

Comment: So you think ‘take place’ is better than ‘be held’?

Comment: @Sasan it's not "better" I just think "take place" a little less formal sounding. It's down to style.

Comment: The choice between *be held* and *take place* may be significant because *held* suggests an event in the way in which *take place* doesn't.

Comment: Incidentally, the ambiguity of *book launch* is parallel to that of *opening*, as applied to something like an exhibition. 'The opening will take place this Thursday' usually means that some sort of an event (party, reception, ceremony) will take place on Thursday, but it can mean merely that Thursday is the first day when the public will be able to view the exhibition.